# Java Binary Search Tree Prefixes

Tags: java, dictionary, binary-search-tree

I am writing a program in Java that takes words and definitions, places both the word and definition in a node object, and places that node in a binary search tree dictionary sorted lexicographically by word.

I am trying to create an option for the user to find all tree words that begin with a certain prefix of letters. For instance, given the input "ap", the program might return the words "appease", "apple", "apply", "apron", etc. However, I have no idea how to implement this. My binary search tree class has a find method and a traversal method (using iterators), but I don't know how to use those to search through the node objects, as the dictionary class (that stores the nodes in the tree) cannot handle anything like that. Does anyone have any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Why a binary tree? Unless your alphabet only has two letters, it seems not the most appropiate structure for it.

Comment: I'm storing nodes within the binary search tree that contain the word and definition, and these nodes are sorted alphabetically based on the word contained in the node. My implementation works great so far, from what I have tested.

Comment: Until now... If instead of a binary tree you use the usual structure (first node empty word, each children is a letter 'a', 'b...), only create children that are in the dictionary... so for 'dog', you would search from root the children 'd', its grandchildren 'o', and its grandgrandchildren 'g', if all of them exists the word is in the dictionary. And any words that begin with 'dog' will be find as the subtree under the 'g'.(This structure has a name but I am too lazy to google it now).

Comment: The specifications I was provided with tell me to use a binary search tree. I do know about trees with more than two children per parent, but unfortunately can't use them for this program.

Comment: Then it should be a run in depth of the tree. Search the position where the prefix would be, and explore 1) its right child subtree, then 2) its parent and begin again using the parent, until you find a word that does not begin with the prefix